Given a pandas DataFrame with several columns containing NaNs, the goal is to efficiently find the last non-null value for each row
Given a pandas DataFrame with several columns containing potentially missing values (NaN),
the goal is to efficiently find the last non-null value for each row.
A similar question using polars DataFrame and solution  is here: Fill null values with the closest non-null value from other columns
data = {
    "product_id": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
    "col1": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",],
    "col2": ["b", None, "b", None, "b", None, "b", None, "b"],
    "col3": ["c", None, "c", None, None, None, None, None, None],
    "col4": [None, None, None, None, None, "d", None, None, "d"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Expected Output:
  product_id col1  col2  col3  col4  row_wise_last_non_nulls
0          1    a     b     c  None                        c
1          2    a  None  None  None                        a
2          3    a     b     c  None                        c
3          4    a  None  None  None                        a
4          5    a     b  None  None                        b
5          6    a  None  None     d                        d
6          7    a     b  None  None                        b
7          8    a  None  None  None                        a
8          9    a     b  None     d                        d


Related: First non-null value per row from a list of Pandas columns

Most efficient for huge datasets
import numpy as np

# Convert DataFrame to numpy array in reverse order
dfvalues_numpy = df.iloc[:, ::-1].values
print(dfvalues_numpy)

[[None 'c' 'b' 'a' '1']
 [None None None 'a' '2']
 [None 'c' 'b' 'a' '3']
 [None None None 'a' '4']
 [None None 'b' 'a' '5']
 ['d' None None 'a' '6']
 [None None 'b' 'a' '7']
 [None None None 'a' '8']
 ['d' None 'b' 'a' '9']]

# Find the first non-null value for each row
first_non_null_indices = np.argmax(~pd.isnull(dfvalues_numpy), axis=1)
print(first_non_null_indices)

[1 3 1 3 2 0 2 3 0]

get the values wrt first_non_null_indices

np.arange(len(dfvalues_numpy)): This creates an array of row indices [0, 1, 2, ..., len(dfvalues_numpy)-1]
first_non_null provides the column indices of the first non-NaN value for each row
dfvalues_numpy[np.arange(len(values)), first_non_null] fetches the values at these positions.

row_wise_last_non_nulls = dfvalues_numpy[
    np.arange(len(dfvalues_numpy)),
    first_non_null_indices]
print(row_wise_last_non_nulls)

['c' 'a' 'c' 'a' 'b' 'd' 'b' 'a' 'd']

df['row_wise_last_non_nulls'] = row_wise_last_non_nulls
print(df.to_string())

  product_id col1  col2  col3  col4  row_wise_last_non_nulls
0          1    a     b     c  None                        c
1          2    a  None  None  None                        a
2          3    a     b     c  None                        c
3          4    a  None  None  None                        a
4          5    a     b  None  None                        b
5          6    a  None  None     d                        d
6          7    a     b  None  None                        b
7          8    a  None  None  None                        a
8          9    a     b  None     d                        d

For smaller datasets
reversed_cols = df.iloc[:, ::-1].bfill(axis=1)
df["desired_column1"] = reversed_cols.iloc[:, 0]
print(df)

  product_id col1  col2  col3  col4 desired_column1
0          1    a     b     c  None               c
1          2    a  None  None  None               a
2          3    a     b     c  None               c
3          4    a  None  None  None               a
4          5    a     b  None  None               b
5          6    a  None  None     d               d
6          7    a     b  None  None               b
7          8    a  None  None  None               a
8          9    a     b  None     d               d

method 3 :
df.apply(
lambda row : row[row.last_valid_index()] if row.last_valid_index() is not None else np.nan, axis=1
)


Note that argmax will give you an incorrect result if the row only has NaNs

IIUC, you can ffill on axis=1, then get the last column:
df['row_wise_last_non_nulls'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]

Output:
  product_id col1  col2  col3  col4 row_wise_last_non_nulls
0          1    a     b     c  None                       c
1          2    a  None  None  None                       a
2          3    a     b     c  None                       c
3          4    a  None  None  None                       a
4          5    a     b  None  None                       b
5          6    a  None  None     d                       d
6          7    a     b  None  None                       b
7          8    a  None  None  None                       a
8          9    a     b  None     d                       d

